# xpath: how to select all text nodes that precedes or follows <br> tags ? possible for \n?

Tags: xpath

```
text<br>
text2<br>
text3<br/>
```

`br` tags may be self closing or not.

would it be possible for a regular text:

```
text\n
text2\n
text3\n
```

Comment: Is it at all possible to use XPath for something that is not valid XML? If there exist `<br>` without closing `</br>` then that is not proper XML.

Comment: You need to have at least minimum knowledge about XML and XPath. The text in your question isn't wellformed XML document or well-formed XML fragment. Do your homework before even asking any questions here -- your knoledge is too low (missing).

Comment: **possible for \n?**: No, that would be one only text node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can give:

`//br/preceding-sibling::*/text()`

where `//br` will select all the breaks in the document